# Run multiple instances of Microsoft Teams app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have multiple accounts on Microsoft Teams which I have to access.

On my Android mobile the app allows me to add multiple users
and we can manage all the messages from there.

But in Linux the Teams client cannot add multiple users

Is there any way I can do this in Linux?

Even if it's possible to run multiple instance of Teams in isolation?

Comment: It may be somewhat ugly and brute-force, but have you tried creating a virtual machine, or some other sandboxed environment, and running one instance there?

Comment: See note below about contention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting MS-Teams to run properly with one account is enough of a pain for me, but a brute force solution would be to create different users and startup teams under each user on the same display....

```
ssh -x user1@localhost teams &
ssh -x user2@localhost teams &
...
```

**Update**

A note of caution: I suspect that there may be contention issues if you try to use audio/video devices with this approach (there's usually only one of each on a computer). It would be helpful if you shared the outcome of your testing here.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 accounts. On of the Uni I study at and another from another Uni where I also have courses. (same email but different account -.-)

My solution for now is to have Teams installed natively (.deb Package from M$) and and as a Snap (on Ubuntu)

Its messy and in the GUI its not easy to see which starting Icon will start which. But it kinda works and shows me two different environments.

I guess you could also additionally run the Webapp in chrome. Maybe you could also additionally install a Flatpack if that exists at all...

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple accounts you will have chat but no sound on most systems (demonize pulseaudio could solve it, but it is difficult and has a lot of negative sideeffects).
So, my solution (using it on xUbuntu 22.04):
I have a single user on the linux machine.

- Install teams from the downloadable .deb package from microsoft.
- Then I'm installing a second teams from snap store.
  Voila, have 2 teams instances, can log in with different accounts, voip working.